# Is it recommended to call Disposable.dispose() as soon as a subscription completes work?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have an `Activity` in which I am creating and subscribing to multiple instances of the `Single` class (each instance is doing some work in a separate background thread). For each subscription, I'm adding the `Disposable` instance that's created to a `CompositeDisposable` instance which is scoped to the `Activity`. When the `Activity` is destroyed, I am calling the `CompositeDisposable.clear()` method to dispose of all subscriptions in the `Activity`. This, of course, means that all `Disposable` instances (including those for subscriptions which have completed work) hang around in my `Activity` until the `Activity` is destroyed.

Is this okay or should I call `Disposable.dispose()` for each individual subscription every time the particular `Single` instance completes work (i.e. when the `SingleObserver` receives the `onSuccess` or `onError` callback)? The problem with the latter approach is that I have to keep track of which `Disposable` links to which `SingleObserver`, and this defeats the point of using `CompositeDisposable`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. When an `Observable` is completed, `Observable` is disposed of by itself. This is part of the [Observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html):

> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue an Unsubscribe notification to end the subscriptions that are ended by the Observable in this way.

Answer (score 1):

[Yosriz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622641/1071320) is the correct answer but if you do want remove a `Disposable` instance from your `CompositeDisposable` instance as soon as the `Single` subscription completes work (and not have the `Disposable` instance hang around), then I've put together the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class MySingleObserver<T> implements SingleObserver<T> {

    private Disposable disposable;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable disposable) {
        this.disposable = disposable;
        onStart();
    }

    public Disposable getDisposable() {
        return disposable;
    }

    public abstract void onStart();
}
```

You can pass concrete extensions of this class in as the `SingleObserver` of your `Single` subscriptions as follows:

```
Single.just(1)
      .subscribe(new MySingleObserver<Integer>() {

          @Override
          public void onStart() {
              MyActivity.this.myCompositeDisposable.add(getDisposable());
              // do something further
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(@NonNull Integer success) {
              MyActivity.this.myCompositeDisposable.remove(getDisposable());
              // do something further
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(@NonNull Throwable error) {
              MyActivity.this.myCompositeDisposable.remove(getDisposable());
              // do something further
          }
      });
```

Comment: May I ask what the advantages would be of removing them from the CompositeDisposable like this? Slightly better memory management?

Comment: Yeah, it would be purely to not have them lingering around in memory longer than they need to be. But I can imagine a `Disposable` object which has been "disposed of" not having an incredibly large memory footprint so feel free to ignore this if you're okay holding onto `Disposable` objects for a little longer than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will be disposed automatically when needed.

Comment: Note that this has already been said in the accepted answer in this thread. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622641/1071320). Thank you for your answer nonetheless.