# How to dispose of disposable in RxJava2.0

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm new to Rx world and I've seen multiple example of how to dispose of a `Disposable` but I don't quite understand the difference. I'm using RxJava 2.0 (v2.2.17) and RxAndroid (v2.1.1).

My question is what's the difference between case 1 and case 2 ? Which one of those two cases to prefer in your application ?

**Case 1:**

```
private val compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

adsApiService.getVideos()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { v -> Log.d("video", v.toString()) },
            { e -> Log.d("video", e.toString()); compositeDisposable.dispose() },
            { compositeDisposable.dispose() },
            { disposable -> compositeDisposable.add(disposable)}
        )
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable? = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        compositeDisposable?.add(api.getVideosAds())
    }

    override fun onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy()
        compositeDisposable?.dispose()
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why in example 2 your clear disposable in `onPause`

Comment: If you are learning and starting to introduce RxJava/RxAndroid in your project. I'll recommend you to use/learn kotlin coroutines instead.

Comment: @xinaiz the clear is optional indeed. I'll edit it so it'll be less confusing.


- I've seen just a little of coroutines, I don't know where to begin with it, and it seems longer to implement. I've gone for RxJava because it'll be useful later for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally? Neither.

You should learn how to use `ViewModel`s, and keep your `CompositeDisposable` there, and clear it in `onCleared()` method.

Also, there are some problems with your examples:

**Case 1**

You should simply add disposable to `compositeDisposable`, not sure why you pass 2 additional lambdas to `subscribe`:

```
compositeDisposable += adsApiService.getVideos()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(
    { v -> Log.d("video", v.toString()) },
    { e -> Log.d("video", e.toString()) }
  )
```

In this case, you actually don't clear correctly the `compositeDisposable`, because it's not attached to any lifecycle (`Activity`, `Fragment`, or `ViewModel`)

**Case 2**

No need for question mark in statement:

`private var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable? = CompositeDisposable()`

This example is semantically correct, although `api` should be hidden in `ViewModel` (MVVM architecture) or `Presenter` (MVP architecture), or any architecture. Having everything in view class (`MainActivity`) is terrible practice and is extra hard to maintain.

Comment: Case1: subcribe can take 4 arguments, `onNext`,`onError`,`onComplete`,`onSubscribe` I don't see the point of not using them as they are available.

Case2: The question mark is a typo. I'm currently alone in a big project, not really experienced in MVVM, I know some MVP but not enough to implement it correctly. I wasn't going to put everything in MainActivity, the `api` is set `by lazy` I just didn't show it as it wasn't revelant to the case.

Comment: Ok, I understand `onSubscribe` usage. But `onComplete` usage doesn't do anything useful, the flow is already completed so there is nothing to dispose of.

Comment: True, I read an issue on the [github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5283) a bit too fast [(another ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614934/is-it-recommended-to-call-disposable-dispose-as-soon-as-a-subscription-complet) and though I had to `dispose`of it myself. So the first case is useless because it's already what's happening in the background without me needing to write it again.